# Creating Image on iOS and Attempting to assign image to UIImageView Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create an image by going over each pixel in a buffer and assigning it a color based on the character in a const char *, and when I try to add the image to an image view, get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  Please help.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageEncryptingString:(NSString *)string{
    NSUInteger width = string.length;
    NSUInteger height = string.length;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    UInt8 *data = (UInt8*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(UInt8));
    const char * cryptoString = [string UTF8String];
    float red   = 0.0f;
    float green = 0.5f;
    float blue  = 0.5f;
    float alpha = 1.0f;
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        red = 1.0 / cryptoString[j];
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {


            int index = 4*(i+j*width);
            data[index]  =255*red;
            data[++index]=255*green;
            data[++index]=255*blue;
            data[++index]=255*alpha;

        }
    }

        // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,

                                     provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

        //Clean up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        // Don't forget to free(data) when you are done with the CGImage

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    free(image);
    free(data);
    return img;
}
```

This is the code I am using to create the image (It is a category on UIImage)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageEncryptingString:@"Hello World How are you doing?"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

This is the code I am trying to use to create the image view.

And this is the debugger output I am able to get:

```
(lldb) po image.CGImage
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6353946e).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb) p image.CGImage
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6353946e).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)
```

The program will not even crash while running connected to the debugger, It just continues to highlight the line `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `CFRelease(image)` on your CGImageRef instead of `free` in your `imageEncryptingString:` method